# why do I get this Out Of Memory Exception?

Tags: c#, .net, bitmap

I have this C# segment code:

```
  string fileName = Path.GetTempPath() + "\\temp.bmp";
        image.Save(fileName);
        bmp = (Bitmap)Image.FromFile(fileName);
```

On this row:
  bmp = (Bitmap)Image.FromFile(fileName);

I get this exception:

```
**System.OutOfMemoryException was unhandled
Message=Out of memory.
Source=System.Drawing
StackTrace:
   at System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(String filename, Boolean useEmbeddedColorManagement)
   at System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(String filename)
   at WindowsFormsApplication1.ShowContoursForm..ctor(Templates samples, IImage image) in C:\Michael work\MyContourAnalysis\WindowsFormsApplication1\ShowContoursForm.cs:line 40
   at WindowsFormsApplication1.Form1.tsbDislpayContours_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Michael work\MyContourAnalysis\WindowsFormsApplication1\MainForm.cs:line 170
   at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem.RaiseEvent(Object key, EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripButton.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem.HandleClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem.HandleMouseUp(MouseEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem.FireEventInteractive(EventArgs e, ToolStripItemEventType met)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem.FireEvent(EventArgs e, ToolStripItemEventType met)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStrip.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mea)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStrip.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
   at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(Form mainForm)
   at WindowsFormsApplication1.Program.Main() in C:\Michael work\MyContourAnalysis\WindowsFormsApplication1\Program.cs:line 18
   at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
   at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean ignoreSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
```

InnerException: 
**

Any Idea why do I get this exception and how can I fix it?

Comment: what is the size of temp.bmp ?

Comment: bmp is an empty object that I create:

 Bitmap bmp;

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it's a format issue with your image file. See here on the [FromFile method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/stf701f5.aspx) exceptions.